# Make azure app gateway load balancer limited to private network

Tags: azure

are these the right steps to change app gateway load balancer limited to a private network?

- associate frontend ip pool to private IP
- update the listener front end ip configuration to private IP
- disassociate front end ip from app gateway load balancer?

appreciate any help.

thanks.

Comment: According to you description, you want to use a [Internal load balancer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-internal-overview). You could check your load balancer, if you use [Internet facing load balancer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-internet-overview), you could not change the load balancer type.

Comment: Your app runs on Azure VM or web app?

Comment: we need to manage sticky sessions so we cannot use internal load balancer. hence we are going with app gateway load balancer. But we do not want public ip on it. Load balancer will be connected to virtual machine scale set on a private subnet.

Comment: Hi, do you use Azure Application Gateway?

Comment: yes. the question is around same. azure application gatwway load balancer (not WAF). can i make it private only? and use it like internal load balancer.

Comment: Based on my knowledge, it is possible. You could refer to this [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-ilb#create-a-new-application-gateway).

Comment: What's your requirement for sticky sessions? ILB provides session persistence based on client IP and protocol.

Comment: legacy app, no centralized session state storage, multiple layers. app gateway is good at top with waf but i dont want public ip exposed everytime i make a app gateway load balancer on internal layers of application. checking ILB. thanks for the tip

Comment: @RajanBhayana Hi, does it work for you?

Comment: Hi Walter. yes it helped. I was able to attach an ILB with private VMSS and use sticky sessions. initial testing looks promising. thanks

Comment: @RajanBhayana Fine. I add it to a answer. If it helps, please accept it as an answer. It will help more people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

You could create an Application Gateway with an Internal Load Balancer with private VMSS behind it. It will achieve your scenario. More information about this please refer to this [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-ilb#create-a-new-application-gateway).

Comment: For the custom health checks and logging to function, you need to follow the guidance here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-diagnostics and https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-faq. Ensure you don't put a host name in the health probe and put in UDR / NSG to allow direct access (NATed) to the Internet to the App Gateway subnets. You don't need a public front-end IP address. Setting a custom DNS on your Vnet might also be an issue (but only for the host name I believe)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I am also using an app gateway with an express route connection. What you listed are the correct steps. I did a split dns to handle routing from the fqdn to the private ip